# Shap values on scaled dataset

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, standardization, shapley-value

I am working on a binary classification problem for heart disease prediction.

I have scaled the dataset using Standard Scaler and I am trying to understand the model generated using SHAP values however is there a way to inverse transform the shap values so that I can see which columns affected the prediction?

[image]

I tried the below but it didn't work:
[image]

What I want is something  like this:
[image]

Comment: Do you want the plots to display column names?

Comment: yes, I have edited the question and attached a sample image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X_test_scaled` probably is a numpy array or matrix.
You can transform it to a dataframe with column names by doing something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=X_test_scaled, columns=["colname1","colname2",...,"colnameX"])
```

This should be enough for `shap.force_plot` display the columns names after:

```
shap.force_plot(explainer.expected_value, shap_values[0,:], df[0,:])
```

Comment: this doesn't answer how to apply the inverse_transform

Answer (score 1):

As univariate transformation applied to a model’s inputs does not effect the Shapley values for the model, convert the explanation to the original feature space should just do the trick, see [example](https://shap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_notebooks/tabular_examples/linear_models/Explaining%20a%20model%20that%20uses%20standardized%20features.html) here by set `shap_values.data = X.values`

Comment: We are trying to build a permanent repository of high-quality statistical information in the form of questions & answers. Thus, we're wary of link-only answers, due to linkrot. Can you post a full citation & a summary of the information at the link, in case it goes dead?